# Chrome not showing Google Analytics Cookies?

Tags: google-chrome, cookies

I am trying to understand why Chrome is not showing Google Analytics Cookies _ga ?  I am seeing them for all websites in Safari without issue.  I have checked my preferences in Chrome, but must be doing something wrong?  Other cookies are displayed in Chrome without issue.

Can anyone help me understand why this maybe? Thanks Ian

Comment: Maybe there is no cookie from analytics... otherwise it doesnt make any sense to me as I am able to see my analytcs cookies

Comment: thanks @B001ᛦ just added website I see the issue with

Answer (score 1):

I should have checked the extensions enabled, oh well:

Answer - Google Analytics Opt-out Add-on (by Google) Extension was enabled
Also in Chromium - uBlock Origin extension was doing the same thing

Hope this helps someone else